# Haskell about recursion in list function

Tags: list, function, haskell, recursion

i'm tryin to create a function(i'm new in haskell) which Needs two lists and Returns one List. The List should have all of the  Elements of the first list,who aren't in the second and all of the second List, who aren't in the first.

So:  `func [3,2,1,4] [2,5,1]` should return `[3,4,5]`

I think my Code goes to the right direction, but somewhere in it is a big mistake.

```
func :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
func [] a = a
func a [] = a
func (x:xs) (y:ys) | elem x (y:ys) = filter (/=x) (y:ys)
                   | otherwise = func ys xs
```

Comment: Can you explain the last two lines, because they do not seem to make much sense to me...

Comment: I think you mean the last 2 of my Code. So If x is an element of the list (y:ys) then create the list without the x. And i've tried sth with recursion to do the same with xs but now it should check the first element of ys and Looks if there is one of it in xs.

Comment: But you do not perform a recursive call, with the filtered list.

Answer (score 0):

Pretending not to have any experience with this domain of problems or be very familiar with the functions in `base`, I'll rephrase your problem statement to describe the operation we want and show you how I'd approach it:

> The result of `fun` on two lists is: all of the Elements of the first
>   list,who aren't in the second and all of the second List, who aren't
>   in the first.

To begin expressing this in code, replace "is" with `=`:

```
func l1 l2 = (elementsOfFirstNotInSecond l1 l2) ++(elementsOfFirstNotInSecond l2 l1)
```

Now we need to implement `elementsOfFirstNotInSecond`, so let's start with words:

> `elementsOfFirstNotInSecond` on two lists is: if `l1` is the empty
>   list then the empty list, otherwise if the head of `l1` (we'll call it
>   "`x`") is a member of `l2` then `x` consed onto
>   `elementsOfFirstNotInSecond` of the *tail* of `l1` and `l2`. Otherwise
>   (if `x` was *not* in `l2`) it's *just* `elementsOfFirstNotInSecond` of
>   the tail of `l1` and `l2`

See if you can translate that to haskell, using not-yet-implemented functions (e.g. you might want to use (`isAMemberOf :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool`), and repeat the excercie.

Answer (score 0):

Does output order matter?

If not, you could just use list difference `(\\)` from `Data.List`

```
Prelude > import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> as = [3,2,1,4]
Prelude Data.List> bs = [2,5,1]
Prelude Data.List> notinSec = as \\ bs
Prelude Data.List> notinFst = bs \\ as
Prelude Data.List> ans = notinSec ++ notinFst 
Prelude Data.List> ans
[3,4,5]
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you want recursion and are new with haskell,so solution(movin' in your direction) would be something like

```
func (x:xs) (y:ys) | elem x (y:ys) && (not (elem y (x:xs))) = func xs (filter (/=x) (y:ys))
                   | (not (elem x (y:ys))) && (elem y (x:xs)) = func (filter (/=y) (x:xs)) ys
                   | (elem x (y:ys)) && (elem y (x:xs)) = func (filter (/=y) (xs)) (filter (/=x) (ys))
                   | otherwise = x : y : (func xs ys)
```

But you can see how ugly and imbecile this is at later stages in your learning path.
I suggest you go with simpler and concise alternative.

Comment: and how is a simpler or better way to solve it ? I just thought that i Need to use recursion if i want to solve this Kind of Problems.

Comment: Well,for start you can use very simple function func x y = (x `union` y) \\ (x `intersect` y) .Remember to import Data.List

Comment: Backticks are not there due to formatting of code by SO.So you can use this version `func x y = (union x y) \\ (intersect x y)` or its inline equivalent in the above comment with backticks.